# React QuerySelector returns null on first call (after that everything is fine)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

document.querySelector returns null on lines 37 and 38 (I've marked these lines in the code so you don't have to look for them), when pressed for the first time, and then returns the desired value and everything works. Perhaps I don’t know something about the features of querySelector or I’m just doing everything wrong?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Splide, SplideSlide} from '@splidejs/react-splide';
import '@splidejs/react-splide/css';

const RandomTestPage = () => {
    let i = 1
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [isData, setIsData] = useState([])
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState({})
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

    const fetchInfo = async () => {
        return await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/all-test")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((d) => setData(d))
    }

    const dataId = (data) => {
        setIsData(data)
    }

    const handleAnswer = (event) => {
        setAnswer(event)
        const ansBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button.btnAnswer')
        ansBtn.forEach(Btn => Btn?.classList.add('answered'))
    }

    const checkAnswer = () => {
        if (answer.id) {
            const option = document.querySelector('.btn_answer_' + answer.id + answer.answer)
            const pagination = document.querySelector('.paginationId-' + answer.id)

            option?.classList.add(answer.answer === isData.answer ? 'trueAnswer' : 'falseAnswer')
            pagination?.classList.add(answer.answer === isData.answer ? 'trueAnswer' : 'falseAnswer')

            pagination?.addEventListener('click', () => {
37-line-------->const ansBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button.btnAnswer')
38-line-------->const options = document.querySelector('.btn_answer_' + answer.id + answer.answer)
                if (pagination.classList.contains('trueAnswer')) {
                    ansBtn.forEach(Btn => Btn?.classList.add('answered'))
                    options?.classList.add('trueAnswer')
                }
                if (pagination.classList.contains('falseAnswer')) {
                    ansBtn.forEach(Btn => Btn?.classList.add('answered'))
                    options?.classList.add('falseAnswer')
                }
            })
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchInfo()
        checkAnswer()
    }, [answer])
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="Testing mt-5 mb-5">
                    <h1 className="text-center mb-4">20 випадкових</h1>
                    <hr style={{height: '3px', background: '#757575'}}/>
                    <div className='btn-start-block' style={{display: show ? 'none' : false}} onClick={() => setShow(true)}>
                        <button className='btn-start' onClick={() => dataId(data[0])}>Start</button>
                    </div>
                    {show
                        ?<React.Fragment>
                            <div className="pagination_block">
                                <Splide className="paginations" options={{isNavigation: true, pagination: false, fixedWidth: '51px', arrows: false}}>
                                    {data.map((num, index) => {
                                        return(
                                            <SplideSlide className={'paginationId-' + num.id} key={num.id} onClick={() => dataId(num)}>{i++}</SplideSlide>
                                            )}
                                        )
                                    }
                                </Splide>
                            </div>
                            <div className="questions_block mt-4">
                                <div className="col-sm-12 questions_text">
                                    <h2>{isData.question}</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div className="questions_chapter">
                                    <div className="col-lg-push-7 col-md-push-7 col-sm-push-7 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 questions_img mt-4">
                                        {isData.image
                                            ?<img className="img-fluid" width="500" src={isData.image}/>
                                            :<div>Питання без малюнку</div>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-pull-5 col-md-pull-5 col-sm-pull-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 answers_block mt-4">
                                        <ul className="answers">
                                            <li><button className={'btnAnswer ' + 'btn_answer_' + isData.id + 'A'} onClick={() => handleAnswer({id: isData.id, answer: 'A'})}>{isData.optionA}</button></li>
                                            <li><button className={'btnAnswer ' + 'btn_answer_' + isData.id + 'B'} onClick={() => handleAnswer({id: isData.id, answer: 'B'})}>{isData.optionB}</button></li>
                                            {isData.optionC
                                                ?<li><button className={'btnAnswer ' + 'btn_answer_' + isData.id + 'C'} onClick={() => handleAnswer({id: isData.id, answer: 'C'})}>{isData.optionC}</button></li>
                                                :false
                                            }
                                            {isData.optionD
                                                ?<li><button className={'btnAnswer ' + 'btn_answer_' + isData.id + 'D'} onClick={() => handleAnswer({id: isData.id, answer: 'D'})}>{isData.optionD}</button></li>
                                                :false
                                            }
                                            {isData.optionE
                                                ?<li><button className={'btnAnswer ' + 'btn_answer_' + isData.id + 'E'} onClick={() => handleAnswer({id: isData.id, answer: 'E'})}>{isData.optionE}</button></li>
                                                :false
                                            }
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                        :false
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default RandomTestPage;
```

Help please, I tried everything I knew and found nothing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with react, but it seems that `checkAnswer()` may be called before the html is rendered.

Comment: You should not use querySelector in React

Comment: The real question is, why are you using `querySelectorAll` when you're using React? React is meant to control the DOM based on state and props. You mess things up when you change the DOM outside of that.

Comment: I know about using ref instead of QuerySelector in React, and I consider it a good practice. But I don't know how to implement my logic with ref (I'm backend). Something like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that using QuerySelector in React is not recommended, but in my case the code works like this. In my case, setTimeout helped me.

```
pagination?.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const ansBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button.btnAnswer')
    const options = document.querySelector('.btn_answer_' + answer.id + answer.answer)
    if (pagination.classList.contains('trueAnswer')) {
      options?.classList.add('trueAnswer')
      ansBtn.forEach(Btn => Btn?.classList.add('answered'))
    }
    if (pagination.classList.contains('falseAnswer')) {
      options?.classList.add('falseAnswer')
      ansBtn.forEach(Btn => Btn?.classList.add('answered'))
    }
  }, 1)
})
```